# Site Actions Menu is not rendered on internet explorer with Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I faced an interesting problem. I have a sharepoint 2007 website. I created a new masterpage and changed default design. So i dont use default.master.

I add site actions menu to masterpage. it renders on google chrome successfully. But there is a problem on IE. I cant see a div or text related with site actions menu on html source of IE.

So what could be reason of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure that this is a probled related to unattended removal of some javascript from master page that handles IE compatibility.

Try to compare your master and the default one and to play with removed lines.